# How to create a highchart using mysql data (PHP)?

Tags: php, mysql, highcharts

Yes I know that this question has been asked so many times in stackoverflow in different ways.
But I really cannot understand how to display mysql data in a highchart.
To be honest I have been working on this for few days and could not figure it out.
I am really glad if somebody could help me to sort this out

Here is my php & mysql code

```
data.php
<?php
require_once '../includes/database.php';
require_once '../includes/customer.php';
$customers=  Customer::find_by_sql("SELECT cust_name,monthly_income FROM customer");
$rows=array();
foreach ($customers as $customer) {
    $row[0]=$customer->cust_name;
    $row[1]=$customer->monthly_income;
    array_push($rows,$row);
}




print json_encode($rows, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
?>
```

This will output a this kind of data series
[["Madhava",55000],["Praveen",50000],["Nuwan",120000],["Thilan ",100000]]

Now I want to display this data in a bar chart which should be in following format

```
Monthly Income
^
|
|
|
|
-------------->Customer Name
Figure - Expected output of the bar chart
```

Now I am going to display them in a chart
I have copied below code  [from other website](http://blueflame-software.com/blog/bar-chart-with-data-from-mysql-using-highcharts/) and really do not know how to change that code to make it work according to my requirement

```
 highcharts.php
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Highcharts Pie Chart</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
            var options = {
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container',
                    plotBackgroundColor: null,
                    plotBorderWidth: null,
                    plotShadow: false
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Customer Name Vs Income'
                },
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function() {
                        return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.percentage +' %';
                    }
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    pie: {
                        allowPointSelect: true,
                        cursor: 'pointer',
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true,
                            color: '#000000',
                            connectorColor: '#000000',
                            formatter: function() {
                                return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.percentage +' %';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    type: 'pie',
                    name: 'Browser share',
                    data: []
                }]
            }

            $.getJSON("data.php", function(json) {
                options.series[0].data = json;
                chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
            });



        });      </script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

What are the changes that I should make in highcharts.php to make this work?

Comment: `[["Madhava",55000],["Praveen",50000],["Nuwan",120000],["Thilan ",100000]]` is not a valid json you have to confirm your json, what is your actual output of it?

Comment: @Jai - Actual output is customer name and his salary which I pull out from customers table. Why do you say it is not a valid JSON?

Comment: Do you receive any errors in the console? Because all looks like pretty good

@Jai its valid, when you set xAxis as category type. http://jsfiddle.net/rvp5L/

Comment: @Sebastian -No the console is blank. Yes this is what I want. Can you tell me how do we dynamically add those json data in series?

Comment: Probably the problem is with getting json, because other elements looks like correct (http://jsfiddle.net/rvp5L/1/) so please ensure if your data.php file is loaded correclty. Try to set full path to the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function () {


        jQuery.extend({
            getValues: function(url) {
                var result = null;
                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    type: 'get',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    async: false,
                    success: function(data) {
                        result = data;
                    }
                });
               return result;
            }
        });

        var myServerData = $.getValues("data.php"); //direct this to your PHP script and make sure that right JSON is returned

        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Chart Title Here'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Place subtitle here'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'category',
                labels: {
                    rotation: -45,
                    align: 'right',
                    style: {
                        fontSize: '13px',
                        fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                    }
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Monthly income (USD or whatever...)'
                }
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: 'Monthly income: <b>{point.y:.1f} USD</b>',
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Monthly Income',
                data: myServerData,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    rotation: -90,
                    color: '#FFFFFF',
                    align: 'right',
                    x: 4,
                    y: 10,
                    style: {
                        fontSize: '13px',
                        fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif',
                        textShadow: '0 0 3px black'
                    }
                }
            }]
        });
    });
```

Comment: Whats wrong? Is there any console output? I could help you via TeamViewer.

Comment: It says Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } . Highly appreciate your commitment but I am not using TeamViewer

Comment: Dude, something is wrong with some other part of your code on the same page. Look here: http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/LLExL/ As you can see, it works, I just removed part for interacting with server, so I suppose that your JSON works well as you said.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I was unable to login to SOF for few days. Accepted your answer !!!